# Javascript code is not loaded to work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I hope to be clear!

At first, I'm using Dynamic Data and the codes below are of a TextBox personalized to use for phone numbers.

I have this code below that makes a mask for phone numbers in Brazil. I'm also using Dynamic Data that is generating the pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mascaraTel(o, f) {
    v_obj = o
    v_fun = f
    setTimeout("execmascaraTel()", 1)
}
function execmascaraTel() {
    v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
function mtel(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");             
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g, "($1) $2"); 
    v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/, "$1-$2");  

    return v;
}
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="slm_TextBox" Width="140px" />
```

And I have the code below in codebehind

```
TextBox1.Attributes["onKeyDown"] = @"return mascaraTel(this, mtel);";
```

I hate hearing this, but this code only works on a page when I click New (create an object any of my business logic), on the other hand, when I click on Edit (edit an object any of my business logic), the code mentioned above does not load, causing me Browser say: 'mascaraTel' is undefined.

can someone show me why the code is not loaded when I click Edit and works fine when I click New?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create new Object of what?!!! your Question needs more Details?

Comment: Create an any object of my business logic

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as i understand you have changed default `Text_Edit.ascx` field template that is located in the `DynamicData\FieldTemplates` folder of the Dynamic Data web application (or website).

Dynamic Data uses the same field template for **all matching columns** in the model. The `Text_Edit` field template is automatically used for all columns (*for any object of your business logic*) of type `string` (Dynamic Data uses *alias* `Text` for .NET type `String`) in the your model. By changing definition of the field template, **you affect all web pages where it is used**.

Thus, in order to implement mask for phone numbers in Brazil inside text field you need to create custom field template (just copy `Text_Edit.ascx` and paste into `DynamicData\FieldTemplates`, don't forget remove custom code from default `Text_Edit.ascx`). Then rename new field template to `BrazilPhone_Edit.aspx` and make the changes that would you like.

Then edit your metadata:

```
[UIHint("BrazilPhone")]
public object Phone_Number { get; set; }
```

For more information read article [How to: Customize ASP.NET Dynamic Data Default Field Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).